# Counting characters before a grep that gives as output a list of many strings with different lengths UNIX

Tags: unix, count, grep, character

I have a `grep` that gives as output a list of many strings with different lengths.

the issue is that i want a list of the same size with the character number.

example:

```
grep output => what I want     

agdhetfy         8 
ethfnsjkl        9
eynjfi           6
kjfdbgkasjdfk    13
```

I was trying

```
grep -o 'expresion' | wc -m  > filename
```

and of course it didn't work and i dont want to do it with a for loop... but if there is no other way, I'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) version that supports the `length()` function:

```
grep ... | awk '{ print $1, length($1) }'
```